# Clear cache in android application

Tags: java, android, caching

I don't think it's a duplicate. Well, I explain what I need.. I've got a list of all application installed in my device.. By a click I need to show a dialog that says "Do you want clear cache?" with "yes" or of course, "no". I found this tutorial: http://android-sample-code.blogspot.it/2012/01/how-to-clear-cache-data-in-android.html but seems to delete the data folder. What I want to know is; is there difference? Is there a code only for clear cache and not data of a application?

Code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);    
        /**Clear cache*/
        PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
        // Get all methods on the PackageManager
        Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
                // Found the method I want to use
                try {
                    long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
                    m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you:

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
// Get all methods on the PackageManager
Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
        // Found the method I want to use
        try {
            long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
            m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Dont forgot permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

Comment: have i to write this code inside `onListItemClick` method? Can i do it?

Comment: If you want to have a dialog. You need a call of the dialaog before calling the method of the packageManager. So call the dialog an onClick the ok button call the freeStorage Method

Comment: Oh ok so the "freestorage" is the name of method?

Comment: ok perfect understand.. how can i see how much mb are cleared?

Comment: `desiredFreeStorage` is the free cache? because if call this with a toast returns `0`

Comment: but, this code is for free general cache or for only app i want to clear?